# Sharepoint 2007 STSADM export exports a file, but import cannot find the file specified

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have tried the import and export with and without file compression. Any ideas?

**Here is the command I am using:**

```
stsadm.exe -o export -url http://site.com/sites/legal/ -versions 4 -includeusersecurity -haltonfatalerror -filename c:\export\legalexport\ -nofilecompression
```

**Here is the line in the export log:**

[1/13/2010 8:33:21 AM]: Progress: Exporting File sites/legal/librarians.aspx.

**Here is my import command:**

```
stsadm.exe -o import -url http://site2.com/sites/legal/ -updateversions 2 -includeusersecurity -haltonfatalerror -filename c:\import\legalexport\ -nofilecompression
```

**Here is the error on the import:**

```
Progress: Importing File librarians.aspx.
Error: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800
70002)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.SetGhostedFile(String
setupPath, Byte setupPathVersion, Int32 iVersion, Guid& pguidListId, Guid& pguid
DocId, Int32 lDoclibRowId, Int32 iAuthorId, String authorLogin, String serverRel
ativeUrl, String targetUrlWebRelative, Boolean isInDocLib, Boolean isMigration,
Object varProperties)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetGhostedFile(String setupPath, By
te setupPathVersion, Int32 iVersion, Guid& pguidListId, Guid& pguidDocId, Int32
lDoclibRowId, Int32 iAuthorId, String authorLogin, String serverRelativeUrl, Str
ing targetUrlWebRelative, Boolean isInDocLib, Boolean isMigration, Object varPro
perties)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SetGhostedFile(Object fileO
rListItem, SPWeb web, Guid existId, String fileUrl, SerializationInfoHelper info
Helper, SerializationInfoHelper infoHelperListitem, SPImportSettings settings, B
oolean fileExistsInDb, StreamingContext context, ImportObjectManager importObjec
tManager)
FatalError: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80070002)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.SetGhostedFile(String
setupPath, Byte setupPathVersion, Int32 iVersion, Guid& pguidListId, Guid& pguid
DocId, Int32 lDoclibRowId, Int32 iAuthorId, String authorLogin, String serverRel
ativeUrl, String targetUrlWebRelative, Boolean isInDocLib, Boolean isMigration,
Object varProperties)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetGhostedFile(String setupPath, By
te setupPathVersion, Int32 iVersion, Guid& pguidListId, Guid& pguidDocId, Int32
lDoclibRowId, Int32 iAuthorId, String authorLogin, String serverRelativeUrl, Str
ing targetUrlWebRelative, Boolean isInDocLib, Boolean isMigration, Object varPro
perties)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SetGhostedFile(Object fileO
rListItem, SPWeb web, Guid existId, String fileUrl, SerializationInfoHelper info
Helper, SerializationInfoHelper infoHelperListitem, SPImportSettings settings, B
oolean fileExistsInDb, StreamingContext context, ImportObjectManager importObjec
tManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.CreateOrUpdateFile(Object f
ileOrListItem, SPWeb web, Guid id, String& fileUrl, Boolean fileExistsInDb, Bool
ean isFirstVersion, SerializationInfoHelper infoHelper, SerializationInfoHelper
infoHelperListitem, StreamingContext context, ImportObjectManager importObjectMa
nager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.CreateOrUpdateFileAndAssocD
ata(Object fileOrListItem, SPWeb web, Guid id, String& fileUrl, Boolean fileExis
tsInDb, SerializationInfoHelper infoHelper, SerializationInfoHelper infoHelperLi
stitem, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SetObjectData(Object obj, S
erializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type objectType,
Boolean isChildObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type object
Type, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializat
ionStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream serial
izationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportObjectManager.ProcessObject(XmlReade
r xmlReader)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
Progress: Import Completed.
Finish Time: 1/13/2010 6:49:19 AM.
Completed with 11 warnings.
Completed with 2 errors.

Log file generated:
        c:\import\legalexport\import.log

The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

Comment: Please wrap error in code tags as you nicely did with stsadm commands. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted corrupt files, re-exported, re-imported.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-filename c:\export\legalexport\` try `-filename c:\export\legalexport\exported.dat`

Comment: I have tried that aswell. Even with compression turned on the result is the same. I did verify that librarians.aspx does exist as it successfully exported, but it will not import correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `-cabsize` (with a value of 1024 (MB)) switch, the default max file size is only 25 MB i believe. If the total size of the site's content is more than the (specified or default) cabsize, it will cut off the backup.

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing it on the same server? I've had problems with custom web parts not existing on target servers that would cause pages to not be created.
I have also seen the problem where the order of the export somehow seemed mixed up; it was trying to import a file with a dependancy on a master page that was not imported yet.

Where is that librarians.aspx? What type of page? It is obviously not a standard SharePoint page. Is there something not OOB on/about it?

If you are up for it you can open the export files (they are .cab's) and verify the file to exist. You can also check the manifest file.

I tend to do exports/imports with the [SharePoint deployment wizard](http://www.codeplex.com/SPDeploymentWizard), it gives you more granular control of what you want to export; you could export this missing file only.

Comment: The import is occuring on a different server. After some research I have discovered librians.aspx is from a Lending Library feature that was installed and not removed cleanly. After manually deleting the files and re-exporting, I now have success.